# How to make two cards the same height

Tags: html, css

How can I make two cards for Black African Players and for White Players the same height All those cards is using the same class is there perhaps a way to make it the same height

[image]

```
div.card {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px 20px 9px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #dfdfdf;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100% !important;
```

Comment: What is a `.card`? Where is the HTML?

Comment: You can use flexbox, the shortest will take the height of the tallest and everything will stretch out evenly. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: those are tables inside a div, right?

Answer (score 12):

Flexbox comes in handy here. Notice how the last element (with three `<br>`'s is taller than the other two, yet they are all the same height:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card-wrap {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px; /* gutter width */
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card-wrap">
  <div class="card"><br></div>
</div>
<div class="card-wrap">
  <div class="card"><br></div>
</div>
<div class="card-wrap">
  <div class="card"><br><br><br></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer saved a lot of my time. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;/*whatever size you want your container*/
  border: 3px solid teal;
  display: flex; /*Make sure to call this on your container*/
  align-items: stretch; /*stretches all cards same height*/
  justify-content: space-around; /*some space between cards*/
}

.card {
  width: 150px; /*or whatever size card you want*/
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**This is what worked best for me,**

I set **`display: flex`** on the **container** of the cards (not the card itself)

It is **flex-direction: row** by default when you say **`display: flex`**

and then simply added **`align-items: stretch`** on the container as well...

This caused my cards to have an equal height.
(This solution works only when your **flex-direction** is set to **row**)

Hope this helps

Comment: Since it's old question and the other answers weren't that bad, if you feel answering you should add code snippet to show your solution..

Comment: Sure, if you would like to see an example, I will edit my answer to add a snippet.

Answer (score 3):

If they are in the same row then you can use `display:flex;flex-direction:row;` on that row but if they are not in the same row, you can do it with jQuery. the snippet below will make every div with `class="card"` of same height

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  for(i=0;i<$(".card").length;i++){
    if($(".card").eq(i)){
      var currentHeight = $(".card").eq(i).height();
      if(currentHeight>=maxHeight){
        maxHeight = currentHeight;
      }
    }
    else{
      break;
    }
  }
  $(".card").height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: best way is to use `flex:row;` but if they are not in the same row that wont work

Comment: Did it solve your problem . If yes then can you please select an answer for this problem

Comment: This is probably the quickest solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `flex-grow: 1` for element whose height should expand inside container to account for available space
2. `height: -webkit-fill-available` to overall container
3. `margin-top: auto` can be used to automatically use extra margin to push last element at the bottom

an example of CSS below

```
{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        position: 'relative',
        '.image': {
            width: fluid ? '100%' : '300px',
            height: '300px',
            objectFit: 'cover',
        },
        '.content': {
            display: 'flex',
            width: fluid ? '100%' : '300px',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            flexGrow: 1, // <--- content can expand to fill available space
        },
        '.cta': {
            marginTop: 'auto', //<-- so that button is at the bottom of card
            ...textVariantCssModification,
        },
```