# Java script - make body card in bootstrap in the same size

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

In my website, I've different cards. Each card has it is own content and might have different height.

I have 3 cards each row.. but I want the cards in the same row to have the same height based on the longest body.

You can see what I mean of the body size in the [website here](http://do-calculate.com/).

[image: 1]

```css
.rtl-container {
  direction: rtl;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.item-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 30px);
  height: 100%;
  /* Set a fixed height for each card */
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add cursor pointer on hover */
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  /* Increase the scale on hover */
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Adjust the box-shadow on hover */
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-img-top {
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Ensure the image covers the entire container */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div className="rtl-container">
  <Row xs={{ cols: 1, gutter: 4 }} md={{ cols: 4 }}>
    {cardData.map((card, index) => (
    <Col xs key={index}>
    <Card className="card">
      <div className="image-container">
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={card.cardImg} className="img-fluid" style={{ width: '110%', height: '250px' }} />
      </div>
      <Card.Body>
        <div className="  p-1  bg-success text-white">
          <Card.Title>{card.cardTitle}</Card.Title>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <Card.Text className="card-text">
          {card.cardItems.map((item, itemIndex) => (
          <div key={itemIndex}>
            <Link to={item.link} className="item-link"> {item.name}
            </Link>
          </div>
          ))}
        </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
  <hr />

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make two cards the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223964/how-to-make-two-cards-the-same-height). This is a common problem with multiple solutions. Searching the web for "css make cards same height" should provide a handful of working examples.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please CHANGE the template HTML to RELEVANT RENDERED HTML in a [mcve] - I also tagged this bootstrap-5 and perhaps we do not even need JavaScript

Comment: "bootstrap 5 cards same height" Google it